# Zoom in picture on hover using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new with JS.

https://codepen.io/Maartinshh/pen/VbGOvm

Here's my code:

**html**

```
<img id="imgZoom" width="200px" height="200px" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)" onmouseout="zoomOut()" src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAA20AAAAJDZhZjAwOTE3LTExMDQtNDE5OC05NDdhLWUxYTU0ODJiZTdkYQ.png">
<div id="overlay" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)"></div>
```

**css**

```
#overlay {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAA20AAAAJDZhZjAwOTE3LTExMDQtNDE5OC05NDdhLWUxYTU0ODJiZTdkYQ.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**js**

```
function zoomIn(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
  element.style.display = "inline-block";
  var img = document.getElementById("imgZoom");
  var posX = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
  var posY = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - img.offsetTop;
  element.style.backgroundPosition = (-posX * 1) + "px " + (-posY * 1) + "px";

}

function zoomOut() {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
  element.style.display = "none";
}
```

Problem that occurs: If you see, then when I mouseover picture on left side, the right side (zoomed) picture, doesn't really follow correctly with zoom. What am I doing wrong?

Also, how can I change zoom level (zoom closer)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first glance, I'm noticing that `event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft` will run `event.pageX - img.offsetLeft` if `event.offsetX` is `0`. Could that be it? If so, you should change it to `typeof event.offsetX === "number" ? event.offsetX : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft`

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Sorry, I didn't catch your idea. Maybe you can try to post it as answer (so it's easier to see/understand)? Also, I edited right container where zoomed picture will be shown. Right now, I get zoomed picture in the side of container... How can I center it?

Comment: OK, I'll do that, hopefully it actually turns out to be an actual answer

Comment: Sorry, after actually trying your code and seeing what the problem is I realize it doesn't have anything to do with what I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some calculations to add extra offset to place img at center of the div

```
 var offY = (element.clientHeight -img.clientHeight)/2;
 var offX = (element.clientWidth -img.clientWidth)/2;
```

edited [codepen here](https://codepen.io/kriptontr/pen/VbGoeJ)